# If ACF field is empty show different value

Tags: functions

I have a function setup in my functions.php file which I am trying to use to show a Advanced Custom Field with a fallback value if that field is empty.  Here is what I have so far:

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_map_marker_args', function( $args, $post_id ) {

    $field = get_field( 'Type', $post_id ); // Get this post's ACF value
    $tent = 'tent'; 
    $value =   if( $field == true ){ echo $field;} else { echo $tent; };

    $args['icon'] = 'https://www.muddycamper.com/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child-theme-muddy-camper/images/markers/' . $value . '.png';
 
  return $args; }, 10, 2 );
```

In other words:
If $field has a value then it should be use but if it is empty then it should default to $tent.

Comment: This is a question for ACF's support. [Their documentation](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) shows a way to check for an empty value — see the **Check if value exists** section.

Comment: What you're asking is a generic PHP/programming question which is better suited at Stack Overflow. But basically, `$value = $field ? $field : $tent;` would do the logic you described.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a php question.

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_map_marker_args', function( $args, $post_id ) {

    $field = get_field( 'Type', $post_id ); // Get this post's ACF value
    $tent = 'tent'; 
    if( !$field ){
        $field = $tent;
    }    
    $args['icon'] = 'https://www.muddycamper.com/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child-theme-muddy-camper/images/markers/' . $field . '.png';
 
  return $args; }, 10, 2 );
```

You could do it your way as well, but it's extra coding:

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_map_marker_args', function( $args, $post_id ) {

    $field = get_field( 'Type', $post_id ); // Get this post's ACF value
    $tent = 'tent'; 
    if( $field ){
        $value = $field;
    } else {
        $value = $tent;
    }
    $args['icon'] = 'https://www.muddycamper.com/wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child-theme-muddy-camper/images/markers/' . $value . '.png';
 
  return $args; }, 10, 2 );
```